# What's the difference between CvTrack and CvBlob?

Tags: opencv, cvblobslib

We use structures cvtrack and cvblob in programs for blob detection but I am unable to find the difference between the two structures as the structure members for both the types are same.

Comment: In which OpenCV module is CvTrack defined? I couldn't see it in either OpenCV or Cvblobslib.

Comment: CvTrack is defined in Cvblobslib only. You can check its code in the header file at /usr/local/include/cvblob.h.

Comment: I think you must be using the cvblob library, not cvblobslib (which doesn't have a cvblob.h)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cvBlob` to detect and draw figures defined by contours (blobs). then you can track them, from one frame to another. For this you use `cvTracks`, which gives you a label and a lifetime. you can give also a lifetime limit (if the blob is not detected in one frame, it is saved for a couple of frames in order to detect it again if it appears again, if the lifetime pass, it is removed and cosidered a new blob if it is detected again). Then in some implementations you have a lifetime limit for being active (it does the opposite, after it is active a couple of frames, it is considered a new blob). You can see an example [here](https://github.com/andrewssobral/simple_vehicle_counting/blob/master/package_tracking/BlobTracking.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

There are two different blobs libraries with similar names: [CvBlobsLib](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cvblobslib/) and [cvblob](http://code.google.com/p/cvblob/)

In cvblob (version 0.10.4), the `CvTrack` struct is similar but not identical to `CvBLob`.
 `CvTrack`  has these members that are not present in `CvBlob`:

```
unsigned int    lifetime
// Indicates how much frames the object has been in scene.
unsigned int    active
// Indicates number of frames that has been active from last inactive period.
unsigned int    inactive
//Indicates number of frames that has been missing.
```

Comment: I got that. Moreover I wanted to know the role of CvTrack struct in the programs. Could you please tell me that ?